# TextView displays "false" instead of resource text

Tags: android, textview

very strange. I have a layout resource, which besides others defines a text view:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtSettingsXYMuteLbl" 
    android:text="@+id/txtSetXYMuteLabel"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="@color/colText" 
    android:gravity="left" 
    android:visibility="visible" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
</TextView>
```

The text is definded in strings.xml as

```
<string name="txtSetXYMuteLabel">delta for no sound (sec)</string>
```

No manupulation of the text view takes place programmatically.

Interestingly enough the text view displays "false" wenn I run the app (device and emulator). Using any other string from strings.xml, such as

```
<string name="txtSeconds">Seconds</string>
```

leads to displaying "false" as well.
Only if I change the text to a hard coded

```
android:text="test"
```

the text view correctly displays "test" as expected.

An idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this

```
android:text="@+id/txtSetXYMuteLabel"
```

try this

```
android:text="@string/txtSetXYMuteLabel"
```

Hope this help!!!

Comment: As above <p> Oh my! copy/paste error... lokked over it 100° times and didn't see it. Sorry for bothering and THANKS

Comment: This is how S.O. earns its keep, saves me trouble.  I just made the same silly error, but only looked it over 3 times before giving up and coming here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your android:text attribute to:

```
android:text="@string/txtSetXYMuteLabel"
```

Comment: Oh my! copy/paste error... looked over it 100+ times and didn't see it. Sorry for bothering and THANKS